# Ajax callback values not saved on submit

Tags: commerce, ajax

I added an Ajax callback to **Add to cart form** on two fields : *quantity* and a *date line item field*, because I need customers to choose the product id depending on these values (see [study case](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/115328/refresh-add-to-cart-on-line-item-field-change) if you wish more details).

Everything works fine... except that Ajax values, especially product_id, **aren't saved in cart on form submit** :(

## Relevant parts of code

### Add to cart form alter

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_alter().
*/
function vts_commerce_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if (strstr($form_id, 'commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form')) {
    //line item field callback
    $form['line_item_fields']['field_date_de_d_part_line_item']['und'][0]['#ajax'] = array(
      'callback' => 'vts_commerce_liberte_addtocart',
     ); 
    //wrapping $form['product_id']
    $form['product_id']['#prefix']='<div id="liberte_pid">';   
    $form['product_id']['#suffix']='</div>';

    // ... SOME CODE setting $options

    //overwriting native $form['quantity'] to have a select with specific options
    $form['quantity']= array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Number of participants'),
      '#default_value' =>  1,
      '#datatype'  => 'integer',
      '#size' =>  1,
      '#weight' => 45,
      '#prefix' => '<div id="qty">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#options' => $options,
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'vts_commerce_liberte_addtocart',
        'wrapper' => 'qty',
        'method' => 'replace',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Ajax callback

```
function vts_commerce_liberte_addtocart($form, &$form_state) {

  $commands = array();

  // ... SOME CODE setting $pid and other stuff, messages...

  //TRYING TO UPDATE PRODUCT ID with drupal_render
  $form['product_id'] = array(      
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array(
       $pid => 'product title: '.$pid, // TODO retrieve product title    
    ),
    '#default_value' => $pid,
    '#weight' => 0,
  );
  $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#liberte_pid', drupal_render($form['product_id']));

  //TRYING TO UPDATE PRODUCT ID with $form_state['values']
  $form_state['values']['product_id'] = $pid;       
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;



  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

Either `$form['product_id']` and `$form_state['values']['product_id']` **are changed** by the callback, but when I submit the form, it takes the product id selected on page load **instead of the one passed through**  the callback.

With or without `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;` in my callback doesn't changes anything...

As an alternative (or complement), I also noticed that `product_id`'s callback is  `commerce_cart_attributes_refresh_alter()`, which updates the values given to cart, but I don't know how/where to call or trigger it in the ajax process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, *product_id* was rendered but its value not passed to the `commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form`. This is how I solved it.

### Add to Cart Form Alter

```
if (strstr($form_id, 'commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form')) {

  $form['product_id']['#type']='hidden';  
  $form['product_id']['#prefix']='<div id="liberte_pid">';   
  $form['product_id']['#suffix']='</div>';
  //...
```

### Ajax callback

```
$form['product_id']['#value'] = array( 
  $pid,     
);
$commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#liberte_pid', drupal_render($form['product_id']));
```

It's quite simple once you know it : before calling `ajax_command_replace()` you don't need to rebuild the full form element, just set the wanted attribute, and `drupal_render($form['form_elt']))` will do the magic :)

Comment: Apart, I still don't know why rendering full $form['product_id'] via Ajax (with the code in the question) made it lose its name attribute, and so not updated in cart...?